# Differentials on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say I have an algebraic curve $C$ over a field $k$ and a group $G$ acting on $C$. Under what conditions on $C$ and/or the action of $G$ on $C$ can one conclude that $H^0(C,\Omega^1_C)^G = H^0(C/G,\Omega^1_{C/G})$ holds?

For example, if the morphism $C \to C/G$ has some ramification, what can one say? Could it be that as long as both $C$ and $C/G$ are smooth and projective, this equality holds, for example?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is true as long as the map $C\rightarrow C/G$ is affine. In particular, if $G$ is a finite group, you should be okay.

Comment: Could you say a few words about why this should be true?

Comment: Is $G$ finite? Or is it an algebraic group? In general, it is not clear how $C/G$ has the structure of a variety.

Comment: It is a theorem that $C/G$ always has a unique structure of variety such that the projection is a morphism (if $C$ is projective and smooth).

Comment: generally, whenever you have an affine map, and something about the map is true whenever the source and target are affine, then it's always true. I'm pretty sure what you say is true when C is affine, since then C/G is also affine. If G is finite, then C -> C/G is a finite map, which is affine.

Comment: checking if what you say is true when C is affine is just a matter of commutative algebra which I don't feel like doing right now. Just note that if C = Spec A, then C/G is just Spec A^G (spec of the G-invariants of A)

Comment: Let's say $G$ is finite... thanks for your comments.